# What is the difference between "Look at my eyes", "Look into my eyes" and "Look me in the eye"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-choice

In the movie "**Red Notice**", the inspector confronted a FBI agent (played by Dwayne Johnson) about stealing the egg.

Then Dwayne Johnson says "**I didn't do. Someone behind this...I was being set up**"

The inspector says "**You're under arrest**"

Then Dwayne Johnson says "**Look at me. Look at my eyes. I didn't do this**"

I am not sure "**Look at my eyes**" is not a natural expression in this context.

Why not "**Look me in the eye**"?.

What is the difference between "**Look at my eyes**", "**Look into my eyes**" and "**Look me in the eye**"?

Answer (score 1):

The theory being that our eyes betray us when we lie, "**Look me in the eye**" is used by the plaintiff: not by the defendant! A defendant might, however, say, "I can look you in the eye and tell you I didn't do it." This is probably what Dwayne Johnson's character means.

"**Look into my eyes**" is used by stage and fairground hypnotists. Amorous couples might say it too, though it sounds a bit like Groucho with Margaret Dumont.

"**Look at my eyes**" is used in all *other* situations where our eyes are of interest: when our make-up's a mess, when we've had a late night, we've taken acid or been struck by a pugilist.